# Why is this Java method not returning all XML Elements?

Tags: java, xml

I'm working on reading DMX Values from an XML document.  The method only returns one node from the element that I'm trying to pull from but there should be 512.

Here is the method:

```
public static void readXML(int cueNo){
        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File(MixWindow.Globals.fileLoc);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cue");
            System.out.println("-----------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

               Node nNode = (Node) nList.item(temp);
               if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                  System.out.println("Cue Name : " + getTagValue("Cue_Name", eElement));
                  System.out.println("Cue Number : " + getTagValue("Cue_Number", eElement));
                      //System.out.println("Nick Name : " + getTagValue("nickname", eElement));
                  //System.out.println("Salary : " + getTagValue("salary", eElement));

               }


            }
            NodeList nListII = doc.getElementsByTagName("DMX");
            //nListII = doc.getElementsByTagName("DMX");
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            int length = nListII.getLength();
            System.out.println("DMX Length:  " + length);
            for (int tempII = 0; tempII < nListII.getLength(); tempII++) {

                   Node nNodeII = (Node) nListII.item(tempII);
                   if (nNodeII.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                      Element eElement = (Element) nNodeII;

                      System.out.println("DMX Chnl: " + getTagValue("DMX_Chnl", eElement));
                      System.out.println("DMX Val: " + getTagValue("DMX_Val", eElement));
                          //System.out.println("Nick Name : " + getTagValue("nickname", eElement));
                      //System.out.println("Salary : " + getTagValue("salary", eElement));

                   }


                }

          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
        private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

            Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

            return nValue.getNodeValue();
        }
    }
```

Here is a portion of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ShowFile>
<Cue>
<Cue_Name>stuff and junk</Cue_Name>
<Cue_Number>1</Cue_Number></Cue>
<DMX>
<DMX_Chnl>1</DMX_Chnl>
    <DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val>
<DMX_Chnl>2</DMX_Chnl>
    <DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val>
<DMX_Chnl>3</DMX_Chnl>
    <DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val>
<DMX_Chnl>4</DMX_Chnl>
        <DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val>
......
    <DMX_Chnl>512</DMX_Chnl>
        <DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val>
```

System.out created this:

```
Cue Name : stuff and junk
Cue Number : 1
-----------------------
DMX Length:  1
DMX Chnl: 1
DMX Val : 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

shortened xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ShowFile><Cue><Cue_Name>Stuff and Junk</Cue_Name><Cue_Number>1</Cue_Number></Cue><DMX><DMX_Chnl>1</DMX_Chnl><DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val><DMX_Cue>1</DMX_Cue><DMX_Chnl>2</DMX_Chnl><DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val><DMX_Cue>1</DMX_Cue><DMX_Chnl>3</DMX_Chnl><DMX_Val>0</DMX_Val><DMX_Cue>1</DMX_Cue><DMX_Chnl>4</DMX_Chnl></DMX></ShowFile>
```

added loop:

```
if (nNodeII.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                      Element eElement = (Element) nNodeII;

                      NodeList childNodes = nNodeII.getChildNodes();
                        String result = new String();
                        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
                          Node node = childNodes.item(i);
                      String dcName = node.getNodeName();
                      String dcVal = node.getNodeValue();
                      System.out.println("DMX stuff:  " + dcName + " " + dcVal);
                                                }
                   }
```

Comment: Can you shorten your Xml file and provide the complete shortened Xml and output thereof, please? Currently, I can't quite tell where the second mention of `Cue Name` and `Cue Number` come from in your output; if I get your code correctly, for that to happen, there would have to be several `<Cue>` elements in your Xml document, right?

Comment: From your XML it looks like you have 512 DMX_Chnl and 512 DMX_Val elements, but only one DMX.

Answer (score 2):

Java and the XML parser behave correctly.

But **you expect the document to have a different structure than it actually does**! So you are looking in the wrong place for nodes, and thus not finding nodes there.

There is **only one DMX** element. You want to enumerate the *children*, not the DMX elements.
(i.e. you want to have DMX_Chnl elements, and these are *not* each wrapped in a separate DMX node)

Comment: I think this is what I need to do.  When I loop through the children I can return node names, but all of the values return null.  I'll add the loop above.

Comment: Pay attention to text nodes. You probably have a lot of text nodes containing nothing than a newline inbetween of the elements that you are actually looking for.

Comment: An xpath based API might be more convenient for you than this low-level API you are currently working with. And in fact, an XML Pull API might work very well for you, too.